# how can I use css and js to draw meteor from point to point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I intent to use css tricks to draw something like meteor which can move from one point to another point.Visual effect likes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRRv1.jpg)

I have done a demo, but it only can move from a given point to another given point."meteor" contains two div.The first div is a rounded rectangle, the border-width property of the second div is "0px 90px 2px 90px".
css code is below:

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.space {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #121212;
}

.star {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FFF;
    top: 100px;
    left: 400px;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    animation: star-ani 6s infinite ease-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.star:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    border-width: 0px 90px 2px 90px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate3d(1px, 3px, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

@keyframes star-ani {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0) rotate(0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0) translate3d(-200px, 200px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0) translate3d(-200px, 200px, 0);
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0) translate3d(-200px, 200px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0) translate3d(-300px, 300px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0) translate3d(-300px, 300px, 0);
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0) translate3d(-300px, 300px, 0);
    }
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goo5skc9/)

Is it possible to use a elegant method to achieve the visual effect.
I am very very sorry for my poor English. T_T

Comment: so do you want to set the two points dynamically and then start the animation via JS?

Comment: yeah,both css and js are OK!

Comment: vijayP  ,you get it.

Comment: i will be checking this but not sure how much time it will take.

Comment: vijayP, thx for you help!